# Can this site be merged with answers.ros.org?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There doesn't seem to be a critical mass of users here.  There is only a single question from this year that is on the top upvotes page, with all of 3 votes.

It can be more productive to put a question on answers.ros.org because there are more active users there, but then you lose the Gazebo developers.  Cross-posting sometimes works.

If not a complete merging, maybe karma and user accounts could be pooled somehow?

There is this question from two years ago about trying to bootstrap karma http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/300/can-someone-with-15-karma-up-vote-a-few-of-the/, the user answered their own question and eventually got some more points, but of course no one else upvoted that question or answer.  (trying to access their profile at http://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/ gives a 500 internal error currently, perhaps another argument for merging if maintaining this site is a burden)

I do find a lot of useful answers on this site but have no way to vote for them, and for the most part no one else either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7419/can-this-site-be-merged-with-answers.ros.org?/) by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looking at only one aspect of a site, in this case Top Upvotes, will not give you a complete picture of the Gazebo community. There are around 1000 users on answers.gazebosim.org, let's be generous and say 50% of them are inactive/spam/etc. A group of 500 people with over 1,500 questions is not trivial.

I'm also looking at the questions that get asked, the frequency at which they are asked (around 10 on an average day), and who is answering the questions. In terms of karma and voting. As of this writing, 335 people can up vote. I've lowered the up vote limit to 1.

Merging with answers.ros.org is not appropriate because Gazebo is a standalone application. Gazebo predates ROS by about 5 years, and has an active community that does not use ROS. A dedicated site for Gazebo also creates a centralized place for simulation questions.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-11-17**:
Lowering the vote limit is a great step, perhaps it can be raised to two or three if enough activity is generated.   (I've noticed the opencv answers site gets a ton of spam, maybe thresholds are too low there, or they need to empower more users to flag and delete the spam).

**Comment by [craig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3779/craig/) on 2017-10-19**:
Upvoted because Gazebo and ROS are separate applications. I'm a Gazebo user with no interest in ROS, and I think that if the sites were merged I'd start receive ROS-related answers to my questions.
Perhaps the question should be how to increase activity in the existing community?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm a gazebo physics developer, and I guess I don't know much about the mechanics of this answers site with karma and voting. I upvoted your question.

There are certainly more active users on answers.ros.org.

I'll raise this at OSRF.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2